Error al momento de consumir una web service soap privada en proyecto desarrollado en .net 2008
Tengo una wsdl, la cual es privada tengo las credenciales para consumirla pero al momento que le agrego el codigo para utilizarla me aparece un mensaje: "se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de envió", ya realice los Dto's del request como del response, ademas agregue funciones para el envio y respuesta de xml y al momento de realizar un ping a la direccion si tengo respuesta pero con el codigo  no tengo respuesta del servidor en mi proyecto. Les agradezco cualquier apoyo.

Así es difícil responderte, coloca imágenes del paso a paso que estás haciendo e incluye una imagen del wsdl entrando por el navegador. En cualquier caso, intenta con soapUI a ver si te da el mismo problema

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

lo que trato de preguntar mis estimados es: que pasos tengo que seguira para poder consumir una web service soap en mi proyecto que esta creado en .net (vs2008) la wsdl no es publica, investigando encontre que tengo que crear Dtos del request y response con su clases proxy para poder utilizar la respuesta, gracias.
